# Using an N-channel FET as a switch

Tags: fet, topology, transmission-gate

I want to use an N-channel FET as a pass gate SPST switch to let an FTDI reset signal through to to my microcontroller or not, based on an independent signal.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5H7Nh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I want the FTDI-DTR signal to be capable of resetting the MCU when the 0V/3.3V Control signal is high, and not otherwise. Does the circuit above using an N-channel FET (with the source connected to MCU_NRST and the drain connected to FTDI-DTR), achieve this purpose? If not, what should I change / do instead?

**UPDATE**

Since people put me on to using discrete logic gates for this function, I would like to expand the question slightly.

What I really want is to implement this function table:

```
CTRL   FTDI  OUT
 0      0     0
 0      1     Z
 1      0     Z
 1      1     Z
```

... I need the open-drain output so that I can still have a push-button attached and not have it fight an active output when pushed. I do not care which sense of the CTRL signal 'enables' the FTDI signal, and the FTDI signal is itself open-drain (so I don't care about its high state). Are there logic chips that implement this function directly, or do I need to compose a solution from multiple chips (e.g. SN74LVC1G38 with active inverters on both inputs).

Comment: It can be solved with gates, however  I updated my answer to add a diagram showing how the circuit will work if source and drain are swapped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Does the circuit above using an N-channel FET (with the source
> connected to MCU_NRST and the drain connected to FTDI-DTR), achieve
> this purpose?*

No it won't work because, irrespective of the gate signal, if FTDI-DTR goes low it will pull the reset pin low via the body diode in the MOSFET. In other words the gate control signal has zero effect.

> *If not, what should I change / do instead?*

I'd use an OR gate. When both control and FTDI input are low the MCU receives a low and thus causes it to reset. If either input is high then the output is high and the MCU won't reset. You can use [this one](https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/Texas-Instruments/SN74AHC1G32DBVR?qs=IEl3ej0IqwA4lppRQbnCFA%3D%3D&mgh=1&vip=1&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAjw7-SvBhB6EiwAwYdCAexEQM8ZbFHunUiQsy2a6cmVdXkGFzhfkPdQ35LmztaE-GH2bBJt3RoCqQMQAvD_BwE). It's an SN74AHC1G32 in a SOT23 package.

**Question edit asks to use a switch**

Put a resistor in series with the OR-gate output such as 10 kΩ. This now acts like the pull-up in your edited diagram and allows a pushbutton to be used as a manual reset switch.

Comment: Thanks, an OR gate is an elegant solution to my problem, good suggestion!

Comment: @vicatcu using an or-gate does invert the sense of the control pin so, beware of that. You may wish to add a little SOT23 inverter if you must not change the sense of the control pin or, use the chip described by Spehro.

Comment: Re-opened the question, fyi

Comment: @vicatcu normally I would have rolled your question back but, as it was such a simple modification, I have edited my answer. Please don't evolve the question any more. See the edit in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would swap the source and drain of M1.  The body diode is not shown.  As drawn, the DTR signal would pull NRST down independent of the control signal.

If source and drain are swapped, since when DTR is low, VGS of the NMOS will be approximately 3.3V.  When DTR is high, the 10k resistor will pull NRST up.

[image]

Comment: If the RESET switch SW1 is closed, it will short the DTR at 3.3V to GND through the body diode and damaging it.

Answer (score 2):

> What I really want is to implement this function table:
>
> ```
> CTRL   FTDI  OUT
> 0      0     0
> 0      1     Z
> 1      0     Z
> 1      1     Z
> ```

[One](https://tinyurl.com/yktjg597) of the simplest circuits to solve your problem is below using just 1 PNP transistor (say 2N3906).

[image]

If you wish the output to be closer to 0V when both CTRL and FTDI-DTR are 0V, use the [2 NPN transistors](https://tinyurl.com/ymn38t3h) solution below.

[image]

Edit:
My earlier 2-diode solution will not solve your problem because I misunderstood your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the control output to be active-high as stated you could use a tiny configurable gate such as the [NL7SZ98](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/nl7sz98-d.pdf)

[image]

If you tie A low, B to the control and C to the FTDI output you will get the desired function.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work as is.

Your source voltage is 3.3 normally (pull up).

Your gate voltage can only be 3.3 max according to your plan.

Thus Vgs is always zero or negative and the n type won't conduct.

Worse the N type body diode means that when DTR is low the MCU reset is asserted irrespective of control signal.

Suggest you read about p type FETs which might be easier to use in this application.

Comment: The circuit is similar to that sometimes used for level translator in I2C and other protocols.  When used as a level shift, the gate is tied to the lower of the 2 voltages.  Only 3.3V is used in this case, but the operation is similar

Answer (score 0):

Here is a first-pass at an equivalent circuit with active outputs.  The circuit requires only three gates, so the spare is used to provide a complimentary output signal.  If not needed, U1C can be used for other parts of the overall circuit.

SW1 is shown as pull-down only because that is in the original concept schematic.  If that is changed to pull-up, U1B is not needed and can be used elsewhere.

If reset switch debouncing is needed, place a 1 uF cap across SW1.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Swap drain and source, like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdt2v8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The only way that Q1 can be on, and pulling NRST low, is if \$V_{CTL}=+3.3V\$ and \$V_{DTR}=0V\$.

I've added R2, which prevents the body diode shorting DTR low when switch SW1 is closed.